# $\cos 5 = \sqrt{1 - a^2}$ which statement is true?

Tags: trigonometry

> 1. $\sin 20 = 4a\sqrt{1 -a^2}{\sqrt{1 -4a^2}}$
> 2. $\tan 50 = \frac{1 - a}{1 + a}$
> 3. $\tan 10 = \frac{2}{a\sqrt{1-a^2}}$
> 4. $\cos 65 = \frac 12 (\sqrt{1-a^2} - \sqrt 3a)$

My attempt :

1. identitiy : $\sin 20 = 2\sin 10 \cos 10$

identity : $\cos 2a = \cos ^2 a - \sin^2 a$

so, $\cos 10 = \cos 2.5 = 2\cos 5 ^2 - 1 = 1 - 2a^2$ and  $\sin 10 = \sqrt{4a^2 - 4a^4} $

i get $\sin 20 = 2\sqrt{4a^2 - 4a^4} .( 1 - 2a^2) = 4a\sqrt{1 - a^2}.( 1 - 2a^2)$

2. and $\tan 50 = \frac{\tan 45 + \tan 5}{1 - \tan 45 . \tan 5}$     while, $\tan 5 = \frac {\sin 5}{\cos 5} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{1 - a^2}}$
3. $\tan 10 = \frac{\sin 10}{\cos 10} = \frac{\sqrt{4a^2 - 4a^4}}{1 - 2a^2} = \frac{2a\sqrt{1 - a^2}}{1 - 2a^2} $
4. $\cos 65 = \cos (45 + 20) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (\cos 20 - \sin 20)$

is theres no true statement or am i just wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Assuming the arguments are in degrees:
$$\cos(65^{\circ})=\cos(60^{\circ}+5^{\circ})=\cos(60^{\circ})\cos(5^{\circ})-\sin(60^{\circ})\sin(5^{\circ}) $$

Comment: so only statement 4 true?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Yes, and furthermore, we need the assumption $a\geq 0$. If $a\leq 0$, then $\sin(5^{\circ})=-a$ which would it make false.